# link (which is a ajax response from other page) not working with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is the output on my page from action.php. From firebug:

```
   <html>
     <body>
       <table>
         <tr>
           <th>Trainer Available</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td style='width: 200px;'>
  <a href='http://appsmarketing.net/free/action.php?me=1' id='member' class='member' >trainer1</a>
           </td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style='width: 200px;'>
             <a href='http://appsmarketing.net/free/action.php?me=2' id='member' class='member' >trainer2</a>
          </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

so this renders as:

```
Trainer1
Trainer2
```

when I click this, it goes to url post, no ajax is used.

I am using script to run when user click this link. It is working with normal anchor tab, but with this is goes to the specific url, and doesn't come back to ajax calling page.. actually when i click the link, ajax is not used as seen from firebug.. what is this problem? i appreciate anyone helping me, as i value your time...

This is my script am using

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a.member').click(function(e){ 
     $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: this.href,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data){
                      $("#result2").append(data);
            }
     });
     return false;
}); 
});
</script>
```

With normal html `a` tag, it works..
Thanks in advances...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two elements with the ID `member`. IDs should always be unique. You should delete both IDs as you already use classes instead, anyway.

It doesn't work, because `a.member` doesn't exist when the you try to bind the click event to it. You can prevent this problem by binding your event to a container that exists when the page is loaded, for example `#tabs-2`:

```
$('#tabs-2').on('click', 'a.member', function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();

    (rest of the code)
}
```

Comment: thank u for ur reply, but it didn't work..i erased the id of the link, included preventdefault..

Comment: Could you provide a link to this page? Or else, please include all the relevant parts of your page and update your code snippets.

Comment: is it ok if i give the online url am currently coding or is it a bad idea to tell?? am using it only for learnin purpose.. @Nirazul

Comment: if it's only for learning, it won't be a problem, i guess... another way would be to paste everything into a service like http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: once i click the trainer1 or trainer2 link, it goes to the specific page

Comment: huh? where did you post it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27482/discussion-between-nirazul-and-user2234992)

Comment: :) :) thanks u sooooo much for ur time and interest.. thanks a tonnnnn :)  @Nirazul